# In Navigation drawer, how to refresh title and drawerlist when calling fragment from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, title

I have a dumb question that I'm using navigation drawer for my android app. so everything works well so far. But now I need to call another fragment from a fragment. I can successfully replace the fragment, but i don't know how to change the actionbar title and drawer list selection.

for example:
in the drawerList i have "frag 1" and "frag 2"
so in the MainActivity, i have

```
selectitem(position)
```

function to taking care of fragment replace, title change and also drawerlist selection change. So i can change fragment by clicking on different items on the drawerlist.

But now I need to call "frag 2" from a button in the "frag 1". I can replace the fragment to "frag 2". But once i change the fragment, the actionbar title is still "frag 1" and the drawerlist still show i'm select "frag 1". how should i change this? I can't call functions in the mainActivity from fragment, can i ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the answer myself. I can call parentActivity function from fragment by using:

```
((ParentActivityClassName)getActivity()).parentPublicMethod();
```