# IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet when using BottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I am using a `BottomNavigationDrawer`/`BottomSheetDialog` from [the following example](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-menu-and-navigation-c4f069e579ec), where the `BottomNavigationDrawer` switches between multiple fragments inside a single activity.

While [implementing the `BottomNavigationDrawer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283268/unable-to-set-color-background-selection-for-selected-item-in-navigation-drawer?noredirect=1#comment91516837_52283268), I realized that when the fragments were swapped without using the menu, i.e. by clicking a button in a fragment, [this left the menu selection in an inconsistent state.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535121/in-navigation-drawer-how-to-refresh-title-and-drawerlist-when-calling-fragment)  Also, the solution of using a function in the main activity to trigger the `FragmentTransaction` caused crashes.

```
public void resetNavDefault(){
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new BottomNavigationDrawerFragment();
            navigationView = fragment.getNavigationView();
        } else navigationView = fragment.getNavigationView();
        //navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "resetNavDefault: setting check");
        MenuItem item = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0);
        navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(item.getItemId(), 0);
    }
```

I realised that this was caused by `getSupportFragmentManager` being null [and/or the fragment not being attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647552/null-pointer-exception-in-fragments), and [using `getChildFragmentManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871343/null-pointer-exception-on-getsupportfragmentmanager) was not the right solution, as I do not use nested fragments, only multiple fragments in a single activity.

I also tried implementing this workaround where [the `onDetach` is overridden to make the `childFragmentManager` accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207305/getting-the-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed/15656428#15656428).

[This fix prevents the app from crashing with an NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562394/fragment-has-not-been-attached-yet) (due to the  *`if (!isAdded()) return;`* condition) but leaves the button that launches the new fragment unresponsive (the button does not work) .

How do I navigate between two fragments using `FragmentTransaction` without causing an NPE, and without leaving the menu selection in an inconsistent state?

My `BottomNavigationDrawer` implementation is as follows:

**`BottomNavigationDrawer`**

```
public class BottomNavigationDrawerFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    BottomNavigationDrawerFragment fragment;
    public NavigationView navigationView;
    ImageView close, menu;
    Statuser statuser;
    RevivDatabase database;
    String email, fname, lname;
    TextView txtUsername, txtEmail;

    private static String TAG = "BottomNavDrawerFragment";

    public BottomNavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, container, false);
        txtUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
        txtEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        database = RevivDatabase.getDatabase(getActivity());
        statuser = database.revivDao().getUserDetails();
        fname = statuser.getFname();
        lname = statuser.getLname();
        email = statuser.getEmail();
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        txtUsername.setText(fname+" "+lname);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        close = view.findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
        fragment = this;
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fragment.dismiss();
            }
        });
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                FragmentManager manager;
                try {
                    manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    if (!isAdded()) return false;
                    manager = getChildFragmentManager();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: ", e);
                }
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.app_bar_incident:
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id).setChecked(true);
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerFrameLayout, new FragmentRevivIncidentDashboard()).commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Request Incident", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case R.id.app_bar_housecall:
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id).setChecked(true);
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerFrameLayout, new FragmentRevivHousecallDashboard()).commit();
                        fragment.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Request Housecall", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.settings:
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id).setChecked(true);
                        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerFrameLayout, new FragmentRevivSettingsMain()).commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        fragment.dismiss();
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        try {
            Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
            childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
            childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public NavigationView getNavigationView() {
        return navigationView;
    }
}
```

**My Error Message**

> 09-13 00:26:32.996 28025-28025/com.package.name E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.package.name, PID: 28025
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiateChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:2386)
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:842)
>           at com.package.name.Fragments.BottomNavigationDrawerFragment$2.onNavigationItemSelected(BottomNavigationDrawerFragment.java:108)
>           at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
>           at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
>           at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
>           at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
>           at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
>           at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performIdentifierAction(MenuBuilder.java:977)
>           at com.package.name.Reviv.resetNavDefault(Reviv.java:644)
>           at com.package.name.Fragments.FragmentRevivSettingsMain$1.onClick(FragmentRevivSettingsMain.java:77)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6303)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24828)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First implement the button click event in your MainActivity as in this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating). Then assuming you have your BottomNavigationDrawerFragment instance in MainActivity, just get the view through this instance and make the setSelection call for navigation menu through this view as the button is clicked. Make sure that you are getting the view through instance after bottomNavDrawerFragment.show(..) call is made. Otherwise you will get a NPE error.

Comment: Thank you so much, Firat. I tried the solution you suggested but settled for creating a new instance of the BottomNavFragment on button click, and setting the selection once it is created. This is much cruder, but I figure I can get the code out the door and work on your more comprehensive solution once this code ships. (This is a beta). I will post an update once I implement your solution, hopefully soon.  I am accepting your answer as I am pretty sure it should work.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it helps. Feel free to comment with further updates.